# privacy settings of the Parse.com Anypic

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I read from the Parse site that it can be used to create a social network app with comments features. My question is how to set the privacy of the comments:

1. Can I block one friend, if I block one friend, I can not see his or her posts on my homepage, vice versa.
2. For Likes or Comments under a post:

First, only the friends from my contacts will be able to view my Likes or my comments;

Second: if I comment on my friend Bob's post and Bob has another friend Carl who I don't have in my Contact list, Carl will be able to view Bob's post but not my comment and Like to Bob's post.

What will be the codes to do so? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: which language do you want an example from? I see you tagged more than one? But before anyone provides offers to you in the form of an answer have you done any research through the API or [SDK Guides](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-object-level-access-control)? they have exactly what your looking for, you just have to be proactive and read them. You can set privacy settings for pretty much anything using Parses ACL standards and practices

Comment: Thanks, could not find it in the guides. I mean the settings for iOS app. And of course for Android as well.

Comment: The link I included in my comment is a prime example of how to set privacy on a per object base

Comment: Thanks, I see. I'll read it. :)